# General .onLoad function when loading a package

Tags: r, package

Is there a hook that can be called whenever a package is loaded?  I would like to run `utils::rtags(path.package('somePackage'), recursive=TRUE, ofile='someFile')` whenever a package is loaded.  Is there already a function/hook that would let me do this?  (FWIW I'm using ESS so if there is a hook in there somewhere that would work just as well).

Comment: Maybe `?packageEvent` and `?setHook` depending on what you mean by "a" package?

Comment: Seems like for compiled packages (which is what `path.package('somePackage')` will point you to, this will be of only limited use. (Try it with `path.package("base")` and then open `"someFile"` in a text editor to see what I mean. )

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, there is no generic "onLoad" method, so I am resorting to
using `setHook` for each of the following

```
sprintf("UserHook::%s::onLoad", dir(Sys.getenv("R_LIBS")))
```

as in `setHook('xxx', value=myFunction, 'append')` where `xxx` is each of the values returned above.

Comment: I would have used some variant of `inst = rownames(installed.packages(.libPaths()))` rather than `dir()`, and `packageEvent()` (maybe in a for loop that included `setHook()`) rather than `sprintf()`; these seem to rely more on the API than on 'knowing' what R is doing.